# Count percentage of special values in column using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
x = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
               subgroup = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2),
               type = c("good", 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'good', 'good')
)
```

I want to create a new data.frame with same column group and column of percentage of “good” in each group. How could I do it using only dplyr or I need another package? Expected result is:

```
x_new = data.frame(group = c(1,2,3,4),
               percent = c(0.66, 0.5, 0.33, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(percent = mean(type == "good"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  group percent
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1   0.667
2     2   0.5  
3     3   0.333
4     4   1
```

Or base R (no packages needed):

```
setNames(aggregate(type == "good" ~ group, x, mean), c("group", "percent"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Solutions by @sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114245/12158757) is already really nice.

Here is another base R solution using `aggregate` but with `prob.table`

```
> aggregate(type~group,x, function(v) prop.table(table(v))) # including percentages for both "bad" and "good"
  group  type.bad type.good
1     1 0.3333333 0.6666667
2     2 0.5000000 0.5000000
3     3 0.6666667 0.3333333
4     4 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

or

```
> aggregate(type~group,x, function(v) prop.table(table(v))["good"]) # only percentage of "good"
  group      type
1     1 0.6666667
2     2 0.5000000
3     3 0.3333333
4     4 1.0000000
```